# We swam in the same pool we saw / had seen in the photos

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-past-perfect

Which is the correct form and why?

> 1. On safari we swam in the same pool we saw in the photos on the website.
> 2. On safari we swam in the same pool we had seen in the photos on the website.

Comment: Welcome to SE! Could you tell us which one you think is correct and explain your reasoning?

Answer (score -1):

> On safari we swam in the same pool we had seen in the photos on the website.

This sentence is not grammatical because the rule of thumb is : Use the Past Perfect only when it is required to show that a certain action happened before something else, otherwise, just use the Simple Past as in the sentence:

> On safari we swam in the same pool we saw in the photos on the website.

Comment: The rule of thumb is useful, but it is not strong enough to make the first option incorrect.  Both options are acceptable in American English.